# How to tell Entity Framework to not include a nested object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following Entity Framework query:

```
Exam exam = await context
                .Exams
                .Include(e => e.Strategies)
                .Include(e => e.ExamSets)
                    .ThenInclude(set => set.Questions)
                        .ThenInclude(question => question.Answers)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == ExamId);
```

`Exam` contains a list of `Strategy` objects called `Strategies` and each `Strategy` contains a `Question`.

`Exam` contains a list of `ExamSet` objects called `ExamSets`. Each `ExamSet` also contains a list of `Question` objects called `Questions`.

As it can be observed in my query, I'm chaining an `Include()` to first include `Exam.Strategies` but **did not** chain a `ThenInclude()` to include `Strategy.Question`. However, in my second `Include()` path, I'm first including `Exam.ExamSets` and then using `ThenInclude()` to include `Exam.ExamSets[n].Questions`.
I'm including `Questions` in the second include but when I check the value of `Exam.Strategies[n].Question`, it is **not null** despite the fact that I did not chain a call to `ThenInclude(strategy => strategy.Question)` after including `Strategies`.
When I again checked the value of `Exam.Strategies[n].Question` after removing the second `Include()` and `ThenInclude()` to include `ExamSet` and then `Question`, it is null.

The problem here is that even though I'm not including `Exam.Strategies[n].Question`, its value is not null just because I'm including it via another include path `Exam.ExamSets[n].Questions`.
It is also worth mentioning that all `Exam.Strategies[n].Question` objects will always be one of  `Exam.ExamSets[n].Questions`.

The reason this is even a problem for me is because it is interfering with Entity Framework's change tracker when I call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` and throwing an exception. After the above query, I'm adding and deleting `Strategy` objects from `Exam.Strategies` from a Blazor Server app and then calling `DbContext.SaveChanges()` (this DB context is different from the context I use to perform the above query, the first context is disposed immediately after the above query and I re-fetch the `Exam` from the database to make changes to it). This is the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Exam' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 22}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

The cause probably is that when I add a nested `Question` through a `Strategy` object to `Exam.Strategies`, each `Question` contains a reference to `ExamSet` and this `ExamSet` in turn contains a reference to `Exam` which is resulting in two different `Exam` entities.

**EDIT:**
Here is the code to add and delete strategy objects:

```
public async Task SaveAsync()
{
    // HashSet to accumulate all current strategies
    HashSet<ScoreStrategy> currentStrategies = new();
    using var context = DbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();

    // (ScoreStrategy defines a deconstructor) 
    if (DefaultStrategy is not (1m, 0m, 0m))
    {
        currentStrategies.Add(DefaultStrategy);
    }

    if (useDifficultySpecificScores)
    {
        foreach (var strategy in DifficultyStrategies)
        {
            if (strategy is not (1m, 0m, 0m))
            {
                currentStrategies.Add(strategy);
            }
        }
    }
    if (useQuestionSpecificScores)
    {
        foreach (var strategy in QuestionStrategies)
        {
            if (strategy is not (1m, 0m, 0m))
            {
                currentStrategies.Add(strategy);
            }
        }
    }

    var localExam = await context
        .Exams
        .Include(e => e.Strategies)
        .FirstAsync(e => e.Id == exam.Id);

    Console.WriteLine(context.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 20));
    
    // Remove all previous strategies not in current strategies
    localExam
      .Strategies
      .RemoveAll(strategy => !currentStrategies.Contains(strategy)); 

    var previousStrategies = new HashSet<ScoreStrategy>(localExam.Strategies); // convert previous strategies to a HashSet to speed up lookup (using TryGetValue() below)

    foreach (var strategy in currentStrategies)
    {
        if (previousStrategies.TryGetValue(strategy, out ScoreStrategy previousStrategy))
        {
            previousStrategy.Correct = strategy.Correct;
            previousStrategy.Incorrect = strategy.Incorrect;
            previousStrategy.Unattempted = strategy.Unattempted;
        }
        else
        {
            strategy.Id = 0;
            localExam.Strategies.Add(strategy);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(context.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 20));
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

}
```

Here is my `ScoreStrategy`:

```
public class ScoreStrategy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ExamId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Exam Exam { get; set; }

    public decimal Correct { get; set; }

    public decimal Incorrect { get; set; }

    public decimal Unattempted { get; set; }
    
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Question Question { get; set; }
       
    public void Deconstruct(out decimal correct, out decimal incorrect, out decimal unattempted) 
        => (correct, incorrect, unattempted) = (Correct, Incorrect, Unattempted);
    
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is ScoreStrategy strategy 
        && ExamId == strategy.ExamId && QuestionId == strategy.QuestionId;
    
    public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(ExamId, QuestionId);
}
```

Is there a way to tell Entity Framework to not include `Strategies[n].Question`? Or do I have to explicitly set it to null?

Comment: Please add your code to add/delete `Strategy` objects.

Comment: Without code it's hard to tell what you're actually doing.

Comment: Also I would say that even if it was possible to get rid of `Question` from `Strategie`'s it would not solve this problem.

Comment: @GuruStron I've added the code. Please take a look

Comment: @ErikPhilips I've added the code where the update happens. Let me know if more code is required.

Comment: @AmalK first of all does `ScoreStrategy` override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`? Second of all the root of your problem is that `currentStrategies` have `Exam` instances which are not tracked (with the same Ids that your tracked one have), so EF will try to add them.

Comment: Regarding your question about loading collection you didn't asked for - take a look at [Eager loading](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#eager-loading) documentation: *"**Tip** Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or all of the related entities were previously loaded."* Shortly, it is by design and you have no control over it.

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, they do, I've added the definition of `ScoreStrategy`. And you were right, I tried setting the questions to `null`  inside the `if` in the second `foreach` loop in my code and it didn't solve the problem. However, I also set `strategy.Exam = null` in the last `foreach` loop before the `if` and that didn't work either!

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you! I was actually curious why that was happening.

Comment: @AmalK be really really careful with this, as Ivan noted from the documentation, you may only have SOME of the, not all of them.  I know you are *currently* using them, but this can easily cause issues when it's not included, but fixed-up.

Comment: @GuruStron I've tested it a few more times. It now appears to be working when I set the `Questions` to `null` before adding it to `currentStrategies` in the second `foreach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to eager & lazy loading, and retrieving entities in general, you need to be aware of the potential for the DbContext to automatically populate references that the DbContext is tracking already, whether you expect them or not.

When lazy loading is enabled, simply checking a navigation property to see if it's null is enough to end up loading it. If lazy loading is disabled, and you "check" for a reference that you haven't eager loaded, (A.B) you may still end up getting back a reference "sometimes" because the DbContext happened to have a reference to that (B) object so it populated it when you asked for (A). This can leave you with unexpected, and seemingly intermitted / situational behaviour.

The best way to avoid issues like this, and the reference already tracked exceptions is to avoid ever passing entities around outside of the scope of the DbContext that read them. By using Projection through `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo` and leveraging view models to handle representations of the data you want your view / consumer to see in a consistent manner, you can avoid all of these issues and gain a bit of a performance bump as well.

Passing entities between context instances is a messy business, especially dealing with references. Before you can reliably associate an entity with a DbContext to perform an Add or Update or such, you have to check each and every reference unless you can 100% guarantee that none of those instances might already be tracked. (I.e. using a brand-spanking-new DbContext instance) Even then this also relies on ensuring situations where you might be dealing with multiple references to the same object, that these are indeed pointing to a single instance of that entity, and not two or more instances with the same data. (This is a big gotcha for people when deserializing entities for example.) Before I can associate (A) to a DbContext, I have to check (A.B) to see if the Context is already tracking B, and if so, replace my (A.B) reference with the tracked (B) instance.. Rinse/repeat for every reference on A, and if (B) wasn't tracked, but references a (C) and (D), I need to check those too.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to replace

```
localExam.Strategies.Add(strategy);
```

with

```
strategy.ExamId=localExam.Id;
context.Strategies.Add(strategy);
```